# No ATT packets with ubertooth-btle

Tags: wireshark, att, btle

I'm trying to sniff the Bluetooth connection between my phone and a smart light bulb by typing in the terminal: `$ubertooth-btle -f -t @MAC -c smartbulb.pcap.` The problem is that there's no ATT packets. I only get `ADV_IND` and `SCAN_REQ` packets while I'm changing the bulb's color with my phone.

Version information
Ubuntu 18.04

Ubertooth tools version (ubertooth-rx -V):
libubertooth 1.0 (2017-03-R2), libbtbb 1.0 (2017-03-R2)

Ubertooth firmware version (ubertooth-util -v):
Firmware version: 2017-03-R2 (API:1.02)